# How to do child level filtering of JSON data using Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have below JSON data set

```
[
  {
    "campaignId": 111,
    "campaignCategory": "Diabetes",
    "result": [
      {
        "campaignType": 1,
        "name": "tes1"
      },
      {
        "campaignType": 1,
        "name": "test22"
      },
      {
        "campaignType": 3,
        "name": "test33"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "campaignId": 222,
    "campaignCategory": "Orthopedic",
    "result": [
      {
        "campaignType": 1,
        "name": "Orthopedic"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "campaignId": 333,
    "campaignCategory": "Cardiology",
    "result": [
      {
        "campaignType": 3,
        "name": "Cardiology"
      },
      {
        "campaignType": 1,
        "name": "Cardiology 123"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tired below filter but that doesn't returned desired data.

```
_.filter(summary, function (data) {
 return (post, _.filter(data.result, {'campaignType': 3}));
```

I want to get below data after filtering applied.

```
[{ campaignId: 111, campaignCategory: 'Diabetes', result: [{
  campaignType: 3, name: 'test33'
}] }, 
{ campaignId: 333, campaignCategory: 'Cardiology', result: [{
  campaignType: 3, name: 'Cardiology'
}] } ];
```

Here all the nodes are showing which have `campaignType: 3`.
Lodash or pure java-script based solution will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the inner `result` in advance and take the outer objects if ayn filters elements exists. Then take a new object with a new result.

```js
var data = [{ campaignId: 111, campaignCategory: 'Diabetes', result: [{ campaignType: 1, name: 'tes1' }, { campaignType: 1, name: 'test22' }, { campaignType: 3, name: 'test33' }] }, { campaignId: 222, campaignCategory: 'Orthopedic', result: [{ campaignType: 1, name: 'Orthopedic' }] }, { campaignId: 333, campaignCategory: 'Cardiology', result: [{ campaignType: 3, name: 'Cardiology' }, { campaignType: 1, name: 'Cardiology 123' }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var result = o.result.filter(({ campaignType}) => campaignType === 1);
        if (result.length) r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { result }));
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina, your solution returns all matched child nodes. Just one request can you modify the `campaignType === 3` to `campaignType === 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to find objects which have a `.result` item with a `campaignType` of 3, and if found, push them to the accumulator array:

```js
const getOutput = () => {
  const output = arr.reduce((a, item) => {
    const foundResults = item.result.filter(({ campaignType }) => campaignType === 3);
    if (foundResults.length) {
      a.push({ ...item, result: foundResults });
    }
    return a;
  }, []);
  console.log(output);
};

const arr = [{
    campaignId: 111,
    campaignCategory: 'Diabetes',
    result: [{
      campaignType: 1,
      name: 'tes1'
    }, {
      campaignType: 1,
      name: 'test22'
    }, {
      campaignType: 3,
      name: 'test33'
    }]
  },
  {
    campaignId: 222,
    campaignCategory: 'Orthopedic',
    result: [{
      campaignType: 1,
      name: 'Orthopedic'
    }]
  },
  {
    campaignId: 333,
    campaignCategory: 'Cardiology',
    result: [{
        campaignType: 3,
        name: 'Cardiology'
      },
      {
        campaignType: 1,
        name: 'Cardiology 123'
      }
    ]
  }
];
getOutput();
```

Comment: _CertainPerformance_, only one limitation with above answer it does not return all the matched child nodes.EX: campaignType: 1 filter should return all child nodes which have campaignType: 1.

Comment: Your question did not specify that - best to include all requirements in the question. If that's needed, change the `.find` to `.filter`, see edit

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter` with `some` and `map` in vanilla javascript.

```js
var data = [{ campaignId: 111, campaignCategory: 'Diabetes', result: [{
  campaignType: 1, name: 'tes1'
},{
  campaignType: 1, name: 'test22'
},{
  campaignType: 3, name: 'test33'
}] },
{  campaignId: 222, campaignCategory: 'Orthopedic', result: [{
  campaignType: 1, name: 'Orthopedic'
}] }, 
{ campaignId: 333, campaignCategory: 'Cardiology', result: [{
  campaignType: 3, name: 'Cardiology'
},
{
  campaignType: 1, name: 'Cardiology 123'
}]} ];


var res = data.filter(campaign => campaign.result.some(type => type.campaignType === 3));

res = res.map(campaign => {
        campaign.result = campaign.result.filter(type => type.campaignType ===3);
        return campaign;
      });


console.log(res);
```

Comment: That's not the result the OP needs.

Comment: OP doesn't want to *just* filter - he wants the new array objects to contain a `.result` property which contains *only* those with a `.campaignType` of 3.

Comment: @Abu I edited based on their comments. Read your question wrong initially.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you can get this result with a simple [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this:

```js
let data = [{ "campaignId": 111, "campaignCategory": "Diabetes", "result": [{ "campaignType": 1, "name": "tes1" }, { "campaignType": 1, "name": "test22" }, { "campaignType": 3, "name": "test33" } ] }, { "campaignId": 222, "campaignCategory": "Orthopedic", "result": [{ "campaignType": 1, "name": "Orthopedic" }] }, { "campaignId": 333, "campaignCategory": "Cardiology", "result": [{ "campaignType": 3, "name": "Cardiology" }, { "campaignType": 1, "name": "Cardiology 123" } ] } ]

let result = data.reduce((r,{result,...rest}) => {
  result.forEach(x => x.campaignType === 3 ? r.push({...rest, result:[x]}) : null)
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```